# Drupal Module - Is it right

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I haven't developed any modules for Drupal before and I guess really i'm just wanting some verification as to if this is "right" and I hope someone can help. Its been developed for Drupal 7, and is used to inject a javascript file into the footer of the page

sessioncam.module file:

```
<?php
/**
* @file
* The code below adds the sessioncam.js file in the footer section of your site
*/
?>

<?php
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'sessioncam') .'/sessioncam.js', array('type' => 'external', 'scope' => 'footer')) ;
?>
```

sessioncam.info file:

```
name = SessionCam
description = Module to inject the SessionCam recorder code
core = 7.x
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Yes, seems correct. Have you tested it too?

Comment: Hi @Lenin thanks for the quick response. The tag appears to work as it does what its meant too. I guess I just didn't expect it to look "so simple" if that's the right way to say it

Comment: You learned the first cut. Now you'd go beyond and learn the conventions and evolve. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not *quite* right. The call to `drupal_add_js()` shouldn't be in the global scope but in a hook function. If you want it added on every page [`hook_init()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) would be appropriate:

```
function sessioncam_init() {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'sessioncam') .'/sessioncam.js', array('type' => 'external', 'scope' => 'footer')) ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Clive thats great thanks for the input. Is there any preference over putting the scripts[] in the info file as opposed to the add_js call??

Comment: Actually I missed the fact you were adding to the footer, I don't think you can specify that in an info file so probably better to use the hook method

Comment: The advantage, though, is that you get better JS aggregation out-of-the-box with the info file method. You can simulate that by adding the `every_page` option to the options you pass to `drupal_add_js()`. [Managing Javascript in Drupal 7](https://drupal.org/node/756722) has a bit more info if you're interested

Comment: am I right in thinking then that the code should change to `drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'sessioncam') .'/sessioncam.js', array('type' => 'external', 'scope' => 'footer', 'every_page' => 'TRUE')) ;` to be on everypage?

Comment: Nearly...that will work but for the sake of completeness remove the quotes from around 'TRUE', so you're using a PHP boolean

Comment: are you able to advise how I can make this work with Drupal 6 also? I have change the core version in the info file and uploaded it to a Drupal 6 install but it doesnt work

Comment: The signature's different for Drupal 6, so you'd want `drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'sessioncam') .'/sessioncam.js', 'module', 'footer');`. There's no equivalent `every_page` for D6 though

Comment: Thanks, I have it working now. I wanted to get it for multiple versions as its a project for work (I'm trying to impress). Thank for the help